# Runing angularjs app on grunt server without watch

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

Recently, needed to run angular app on grunt server, but without watching certain files (without listening to changes made in them) and I was unable to.

My `connect` property in `Gruntfile.js` is set to following

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
      // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
      hostname: '0.0.0.0',
      livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
        base: [
        '.tmp',
        'example'
      ]
    }
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      port: 9001,
        base: [
        '.tmp',
        'test',
        'example'
      ]
    }
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      base: 'example'
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm using `"grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.7.1"`, but without `grunt-contrib-watch` it runs one time and ends process. Doesn't stay open.

Anyway to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the keepalive option to the connect options. Set it to true. See README for more info:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect